# MicrobiotaProcess ggbartax change x axis names of samples

Tags: r, bar-chart

I analysed and visualised my metabarcoding data using the `MicrobiotaProcess` package and here is what I got:

[image: example1]

I used this code:

```
pclass <- ggbartax(obj=classtaxa, facetNames="organs", topn=30) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  ylab("relative abundance (%)") +
  guides(fill= guide_legend(keywidth = 0.5, keyheight = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=13), strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "white"))
```

File for graph is a phyloseq and looks like this:

[image: example2]

with this metadata:

[image: example3]

Is there a way to change sample names on x axis from sample's number to corresponding fish name on the barplot? For example, sample 2 and 2_1 to ZR_4.

I tried `scale_x_discrete()` to change names, but due to facet type of graph, it does not work properly. Each facet starts the vector of names from the beginning.
I tried changing names of the row but I have non-unique names (I have done 2 repetitions in my experiment) so they can not be applied as row names.
`aes()` option did not work as well.

Comment: You could try with a named vector to assign labels to your categories, e.g. `+ scale_x_discrete(labels = c("2" = "ZR_4", "2_1" = "ZR_4",  ...))`

Comment: Hi Polyakova, welcome to SO. Please do not add images of data for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). Instead, add the relevant text in a codeblock. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks